# Can a Web Reference Be Exposed from another Class?

Tags: c#, web-services, asmx

the question is simple..

we usually use web reference to consume the web services literally(visual studio). But, my problem is another way round. I need to call a particular web service from a  c# class to make the web service available to be consumed by others.

Comment: What is the difference between your c# class and a web reference class?  Doesn't the web reference already provide that?

Comment: Your question is not simple; it is incomprehensible.

Comment: I'm very sorry for my language mistakes. thank you for your intention.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all, if you have a choice, you should be using WCF on both the server and client. If you can't use it on the server for some reason, then at least use it on the client by using "Add Service Reference" instead of "Add Web Reference". "Add Web Reference" is part of the legacy ASMX technology, which should not be used for new development.

Secondly, of course you can create a separate class library, and use "Add Service Reference" in that library. You can then write a class that has public methods which call the service. The users of this class library will call your public methods, and will not directly call the service.

Comment: thank you, very appreciate it. even I did't well understand it.

Comment: yess.. very good solution nether. I've just got your point here. tqvm!

Answer (score 1):

You can extract the C# code class of a Web Reference by unfolding the web reference in VS, (by showing hidden files if I remember well).
You should find a Reference.cs file which is the proxy client code for your web Service.

It contains everything you need to call your WS. You can copy it elsewhere, include it in another project, change its namespace/code etc. On the long run, maintainance of this file will be a pain if the corresponding WS evolves.

Anyway, if you have the choice, you should follow @JohnSaunders advice on WCF

Comment: Glad to read it. Don't overlook the comments about WCF though :-)

Comment: I'm close to downvoting since you recommend copying a generated file into another project. That's almost as bad as _modifying_ a generated file.